# I have a choice field on a model.py which allows the user to select a field value another model from within my sqlite database

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have a choice field on a model.py which allows the user to select a field value from another model from within my sqlite database. Using the development server ("python manage.py runserver" command choice field is populated correctly) this is populated during the runserver command. The problem I have is I would like the choice field to update automaticaly when we add a new feild.

```
class UserData(models.Model):
    usertype = models.IntegerField('User Type',choices=((0, ("Boat Owner")),(1, ("Boat Manager")),(2, ("Travel Agent"))))
    username   = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True)
    password   = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name       = models.CharField(max_length=200,verbose_name='Name')
    boat_no    = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True)
    address    = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
    phone = models.IntegerField(validators=[phone_regex], blank=True) # validators should be a list
    email      = models.EmailField('email address', unique=True)
    avatar     = models.ImageField('profile picture', upload_to='images', null=True, blank=True)

    def image_img(self):
        if self.avatar:
            return u'<img src="/media/%s" width="50px" height="50px"/>' % self.avatar
        else:
            return 'NO IMAGES FOUND !'
     image_img.short_description = 'Thumb'
     image_img.allow_tags = True

    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s' % (self.edit,self.usertype,self.id,self.name,self.boat_no,self.username,self.password,self.address,self.email)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Boat App User"
        verbose_name_plural = "Boat App User"

#Boat_Detail Module
class Boat_Detail(models.Model):
    BOAT_NUMBER = list ( (obj.boat_no,obj.boat_no) for obj in UserData.objects.all() )
    boat_no = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=BOAT_NUMBER,verbose_name="Boat NUMBER")
    boat_name       = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    no_of_ac_rooms  = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="No of AC Rooms")
    no_of_nonac_rooms = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="No of Non AC Rooms")
    BOAT_MANAGER_LIST = list ( (obj.name,obj.name) for obj in UserData.objects.all() )
    BOAT_OWNER_LIST = list ( (obj.name,obj.name) for obj in UserData.objects.all() )
    boat_owner      = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=BOAT_OWNER_LIST,verbose_name="Boat Owner")
    boat_manager    = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=BOAT_MANAGER_LIST,verbose_name="Boat Manager")
    avatar          = models.ImageField('profile picture', upload_to='images', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s %s %s %s %s %s' % (self.edit,self.id,self.boat_name,self.boat_no,self.boat_manager,self.boat_owner)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Boat Details"
        verbose_name_plural = "Boat Details"

    def image_img(self):
        if self.avatar:
            return u'<img src ="/media/%s" width="50px" height="50px"/>' % self.avatar
        else:
            return 'NO IMAGES FOUND !'
    image_img.short_description = 'Thumb'
    image_img.allow_tags = True
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to be actual code, and put in some line breaks around 80 chars, for readability?

Comment: Is a ForeignKey not something you can use?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the "choices=" parameter passed to model fields are tied to your database migration. In other words, you have to call manage.py makemigrations / migrate every time you add to the list of choices.

To get around this problem, you'll have to create an Enum with your choices and manage it outside of you model. If you're using Python 2, use the backport module enum34. To get Enum.choices to return strings, subclass Enum like so:

```
class ChoiceEnum(Enum):
    @classmethod
    def choices(cls):
        # get all members of the class
        members = inspect.getmembers(cls, lambda m: not (inspect.isroutine(m)))
        # filter down to just properties
        props = [m for m in members if not (m[0][:2] == '__')]
        # format into django choice tuple
        choices = tuple([(str(p[1].value), p[0]) for p in props])
        return choices
```

Then, rather than specifying the choices at the model level, use a custom field in your ModelForm.

```
usertype = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=MyEnum.choices(), coerce=str)
```

Comment: Hi...whatever you said is correct...but am in model.py...not using form....,so is there any idea to solve within model.py